# Error handling with Numpy C API

Tags: python, c, numpy

I have a call to `PyArray_SimpleNew` which is returning a null pointer. I believe I am calling it with the correct arguments, and that it returns null because my machine doesn't have enough memory.

Does the Numpy C API provide any way for me to get information about the failure that's happening? The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html) talks in a few places about an error condition being set. Can I query this error condition somehow?

Comment: If it's a memory problem, it probably raised an exception you can handle.

Comment: @user2357112 Where would I find that?

Comment: [Found it](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/exceptions.html#printing-and-clearing)